# What's worse for performance: adding a new column, or adding together an existing column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, load

I have a comment system in which users can votes on comments. When a vote is cast on a Comment, a Vote is created (for that Comment) with an ip equal to the user's ip address. Then, when the user reloads the page, my server looks through the existing Votes for each Comment and checks if the Votes contain the user's ip address, and if so, the user is not allowed to vote.

**comment.rb**

```
has_many :votes
```

**votes.rb**

```
belongs_to :comment
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
t.string   "ip"
```

**view**

```
<% @ip_array = comment.votes.pluck(:ip).to_a %>
<% if !(@ip_array.include? request.remote_ip) %>
  <!--allow to vote-->
```

---

My question is this: which of these two scenarios would be easier on the server?

**1:)** I create a separate attribute for Comments called "vote_count", and each time a vote is cast, `@comment.vote_count` is set equal to `@comment.vote_count + 1`

**2:)** The server just adds all the Votes together: `@comment.votes.all`

---

I'll probably be rendering around 50 comments on page load, and each comment might have an average of 4 votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would go with option #1 and use a counter cache. As your application grows bigger, retrieving and adding up all those votes will reduce performance.

**app/models/vote.rb**

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :comment, counter_cache: :count_of_votes
end
```

Add `count_of_votes` column to your `comments` table:

```
rails generate migration AddCountOfVotesToComments count_of_votes:integer
```

You'll probably want to edit the migration and add a default value for the column:

```
t.integer :count_of_votes, default: 0
```

You can learn more about counter caches in the Rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Can I use counter_cache on `vote`if `vote` is polymorphically associated with a few other models as well? If not, do you think it would be worth it to create a `comment_vote` model just for this?

Comment: Yes, it will work. You just just need to add the `count_of_votes` column to each of your other models. You could create a `Voteable` concern with `has_many :votes, as: :voteable` and include the concern in your voteable models.

Comment: Then inside your `Vote` model, make sure to change your association to `belongs_to :voteable, as: :polymorphic, counter_cache: :count_of_votes`.